# How do I define a public state variable equals to 1%?

Tags: solidity

What about using 1e16 / 100 as the state variable?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a static variable, you can set it like the example you gived. Otherwise you can make a pure function that will accept a variable as parameter and return 1% from it. Then just use the function when you want to calculate 1% of something.